# Mixing inequality in the paper "The absence of mixing in special flows over rearrangements of segments"

Tags: measure-theory, ergodic-theory, mixing

I can't verify an inequality in the paper: https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF02110361.pdf

The inequality is at the end of the second page in the proof of the second theorem and is shown in this image: [inequality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6RDY.png)

It is in the proof of showing that special flow over a transformation with an ND approximation is not mixing. The author makes a sequence that contradicts mixing. I tried various or probability inequalities, and considering the set $A$ as a long rectangle. This gives me the inequality: $\nu (T_{t(j)} A\cap A\cap Y_j')\geq \nu (A \cap Y_j')- \nu((T_{t(j)} A \cap  Y_j')$ but I'm not sure how to proceed, or if this is the first step.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This paper looks very rubbish. I would also like to understand it since it is also related to my fields but some things do not add up. When he defines the two condition for the set A the first one is relevant, the second is suspicious since you can add the segment of length L after z to add. It will not change anything since it is a zero measure set.

Comment: So I do not understand how one can use the second condition in the definition of A to show this inequality.

Comment: Also for what I understand, z depend on j but A should not depend on j, but I am not sure.

Comment: I think the idea of A is to take an interval and extend it to a column of length L. This indeed changes the measure. A is independent of j. The z selected is dependent on j.

Comment: $A$ is a subset of $M$ as it is written so not necessarily a column. Maybe we need to make this hypothesis.

Comment: It is not necessarily a column but a column would work as A.